# how to restrict capital letter typing in android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to restrict capital letter typing through keyboard on my form.

any one guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what's your goal? Why do you want to restrict capital letters? Can't you take care of them on the validation of user input and use *toLowerCase()*

If you do need to restrict capital letters, the only way I can think of is overriding   [onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before, int after)](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onTextChanged%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and trying to do whatever you want inside it. I haven't tested it, but it might work.

Update: radek mentioned [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html). That solutions seems cleaner than mine, but I've never used them.

*InputFilters can be attached to Editables to constrain the changes that can be made to them.*

Comment: There is no inputFilter or InputType (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) for what he's trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for choosing my answer, but radek-k's is the better one. Anyway, we all learned something today ^^

Comment: actually, let the user type whatever case he wants. we will convert it lower or upper case according to our need so then why to take care about restricting upper case thats why i like answer anyways both answers are good :)

Answer (score 4):

In source code:

```
InputFilter smallFilter = new InputFilter() {

  @Override
  public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
      Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
      if (Character.isUpperCase(source.charAt(i))) {
        char[] v = new char[end - start];
        TextUtils.getChars(source, start, end, v, 0);
        String s = new String(v).toLowerCase();

        if (source instanceof Spanned) {
          SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(s);
          TextUtils
              .copySpansFrom((Spanned) source, start, end, null, sp, 0);
          return sp;
        } else {
          return s;
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
};

EditText vText = ...;
vText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{smallFilter});
```

It is based on Android source of: InputFilter.AllCaps. Tested and works.

Comment: I think he wants it the other way round: no capital letters

Comment: both not working.

above automatically sets keyboard to each time if you turn it off it allows you to enter 1 small character.

and below one giving error 
InputFilter.AllCaps cannot be resolved.

Comment: add

"import android.text.InputFilter;"

after package declaration.

Comment: I have edited my post and cleaned it up. Sorry for making a little mess.

Comment: Don't appologise for trying to help :)

Comment: PS. Make sure add all neccessary imports (CTRL+SHIFT+O in Eclipse).